# From authentication to website - a mismatch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, handlebars.js

I have an `react/express/socket.io` application that works fine without authentication. I have ported the application to use `Passport` authentication. The authentication runs fine. The application runs fine without authentication. However, the two together have a impedance mismatch.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
[idf@node3 react-ts]$ ls -la
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  6 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 23:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 22:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x  7 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 21:49 backup
drwxrwxr-x  3 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 22:32 client
drwxrwxr-x  8 idf idf 4096 Mar  7 01:42 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 idf idf   21 Feb  7 23:25 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 idf idf 1181 Mar  6 23:13 package.json
drwxrwxr-x  4 idf idf 4096 Mar  7 01:26 server
[idf@node3 react-trader]$
```

critically with `client` being

```
[idf@node3 client]$ ls
www
[idf@node3 client]$ 

[idf@node3 www]$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 4 idf idf 4096 Feb 14 00:34 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 22:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 idf idf 4096 Feb  8 00:00 css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf  593 Mar  2 04:33 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf 1362 Feb 14 00:30 index.html.hide
drwxrwxr-x 2 idf idf 4096 Mar  5 23:44 js
[idf@node3 www]$ 

[idf@node3 js]$ ls -la
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 2 idf idf  4096 Mar  5 23:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 idf idf  4096 Feb 14 00:34 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf 16438 Mar  6 00:34 app.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf   348 Feb 17 05:42 feed-socketio.js
[idf@node3 js]$
```

The way I used to display the website without auth was to say:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/www')));
...lots of code here...
http.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listening on: 8080');
});
```

However, after adding authentication front end, if I add the same path this time giving not just the directory but the main `index.html` file, `successRedirect: '../client/www/index.html',`

```
//sends the request through our local login/signin strategy, 
//and if successful takes user to homepage, 
//otherwise returns then to signin page
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
  successRedirect: '../client/www/index.html',
  failureRedirect: '/signin'
  })
);
```

upon **successful** login the browser comes back and says:

```
Cannot GET /client/www/index.html
```

Part of the authentication looks like this:

```
//displays our homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home', {user: req.user});
});
```

It feels like I should be returning `/` in `successRedirect`and then rewriting `app.get('/)` to somehow do the same magic that `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/www')));` does. Thing is, the application is not **just** a static page, but a dynamically generated web page through `app.js`. The real work is done by `app.js` the last line of the file which reads:

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    ...
    },
    ...
});

React.render(<HomePage />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

The file `index.html` is just a shell:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trader Desktop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/feed-socketio.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/jsx" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="main">    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the authentication part of the application, on successful login, we see it is taking me to a file `main.handlebars`, as given here:

```
// Configure express to use handlebars templates
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

This file is inside a subdirectory called `views` and inside there a directory called `layout`:

```
[idf@node3 server]$ ls -la
total 64
drwxrwxr-x   4 idf idf  4096 Mar  7 01:26 .
drwxrwxr-x   6 idf idf  4096 Mar  6 23:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 idf idf   475 Mar  7 00:01 config.js
-rw-rw-r--   1 idf idf  8274 Mar  2 19:28 feed.js
-rw-rw-r--   1 idf idf  2408 Mar  7 00:01 functions.js
drwxrwxr-x 440 idf idf 20480 Mar  6 23:37 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 idf idf  1198 Mar  6 23:37 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 idf idf  7144 Mar  7 01:28 server.js
drwxrwxr-x   3 idf idf  4096 Mar  6 23:41 views

[idf@node3 views]$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 3 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 23:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 idf idf 4096 Mar  7 01:26 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf  756 Mar  6 23:41 home.handlebars
drwxrwxr-x 2 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 23:41 layouts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf 1952 Mar  6 23:41 signin.handlebars
[idf@node3 views]$ 


[idf@node3 layouts]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 23:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 idf idf 4096 Mar  6 23:41 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf idf 2734 Mar  6 23:41 main.handlebars
[idf@node3 layouts]$
```

I am probably missing something very simple, but not sure what the fix is. In essence, I need the authentication to pass control to `express`/`react`/`socket.io` - **not to a static home page**.

Answer (score 0):

The login success redirect should point to the public URL your application is being served from, not a file path internal to your app.

```
successRedirect: '/'
```

Moving your app from static content `app.use(express.static('blah'))` to using a dynamic page `app.get(/,(res,res)=>...)` is a fairly big change in itself.  Make sure your app works using just the dynamic `/` route without the static middleware before trying to add the authentication.

Comment: Cannot GET /index.html. It cannot possibly find index.html without app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/www'))); but if I put that in it on browsing to the site initially, it takes me to the website not the authentication page.

Comment: I added a little more to the original post that I think is a helpful clue.

Comment: @Ivan yeah the change of static middleware to a dynamic route plays a part. updated

Comment: Matt when you say, "Make sure your app works using just the dynamic / route without the static middleware before trying to add the authentication" can you point me to an example of changing express so that I have to "render" the homepage by hand instead of the system doing it for me?

Comment: BTW, I probably mispoke. The page that gets rendered is just index.html which then the middleware calls app.js so this may be easier than I think. See the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It was very easy indeed, but the solution is subtle.

```
successRedirect: '/index.html'
```

is correct, but the section of code has to change so that the `app.use` is **right before** the http.listen. Simple, but it took forever to figure out.

```
lots of code above...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/www')));

http.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listening on: 8080');
});
```

There is only one problem left now. The user can type in http://www.website.com/index.html and bypass authentication. I don't think that is hard to fix but don't know how to do it right now.